# findViewById for webView is null

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to make a simple WebView app in Android Studio, but my WebView is null.  I'm very new to Android Dev.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
// myWebView is null

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.patrick.app2.MainActivity">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you're not calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_mail)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the view before you set a view ID.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


}
```